# Bootstrap datetimepicker no action

Tags: php, date, time, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement the bootstrap datetimepicker and am running into an issue where clicking on the input box doesn't trigger any action. I have double checked my imports along with the code itself following several tutorials, but I am not able to find the issue with my code. The imports I am using are as followed:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have downloaded the datetimepicker repo and have selected the css and js folder and moved them to the main directory.

The code I am calling for the label is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
                                            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                                                <input size="16" type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime" readonly>

                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    $("#datetime").datetimepicker({
                                                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'
                                                    });
                                                </script>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

As I have stated the label doesn't have any action when clicked on. I am not sure if you need the whole webpage to understand my issue but I will post it below:

```
<?php
require('./includes/connection.php');
require('./includes/crypt.php');
require('functions.php');

session_start();
ob_start();

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: peri
 * Date: 2019-04-07
 * Time: 16:48
 */



if(isset($_GET['cancel'])) {
    header('Location: messaging.php');
    exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['confirm'])) {
    if(isset($_GET['reason'])) {
        //Encrypted text
        $encrypted_text = encrypt_text($_GET['reason'], $key, $iv);

    }
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>New Appointment</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark align-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EMR System</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse align-center" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Appointment <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prescription</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lab Tests</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Billing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/sm/20180620/sm_5b29c1b6c8772.png" width="45px" height="45px"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<br>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-5 mx-auto">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    <?php
                    //Running query to fetch physician details
                    $row = get_physician_information_messaging($_SESSION['phy_ssn']);
                    //echo var_dump($row);
                    //$message = "test";
                    //insert_message($_SESSION['ssn'], $message, 0);
                    ?>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="6">Physician Information</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">First Name:</th>
                            <td class="col-md-6"> <?php echo $row[0]?></td>
                            <th scope="row">Last Name:</th>
                            <td class="col-md-6"> <?php echo 'Dr. ' . $row[2]?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Phone Number:</th>
                            <td class="col-md-6"><?php echo $row[3] ?></td>
                            <th scope="row">Speciality:</th>
                            <td class="col-md-6"><?php echo $row[4] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    <form method="get" action="new_appointment.php">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" colspan="2">Reason for visit</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="visit_reason">Enter your reason for the visit. Be as descriptive as possible.</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="visit_reason" rows="3" name="reason"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                                                <input size="16" type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime" readonly>

                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    $("#datetime").datetimepicker({
                                                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'
                                                    });
                                                </script>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="confirm">Confirm</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone point out my issue? (Note: All of the code I have used for the datetimepicker were copied pasted from tutorials which is another reason as to why I am puzzled.)

Comment: First step: user the console window to see if your JavaScript errored out. One syntax error makes the whole thing go silent...

Comment: I did that initially. It kept saying null didn't error out.

Comment: That would be an error; sounds like jquery couldn’t find the element. Shouldn’t be necessary but try moving the js block down to the bottom, just before close of body tag. Also would be helpful to include console message in your question.